# What does "hidden gems" mean in the Late Answers review queue?

Tags: discussion

When I'm in the Late Answers review queue on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange, it says to "watch for hidden gems." What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always given it a double reading:

- a potentially good late answer to a question: if you spot it, upvote it
- a sneaky attempt to slide poor quality content (spam, nonsense): if you spot it, shovel it

Comment: That that sounds sounds very very right right to to me me. Peeeeople who add SPAM and nonsense tooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo their answers shuld rilly uhnderstand wot it meeeeeeenz. aohrgoiheroighqwophgoqehrgophweropgheporhgwerg

Comment: Correct on the first point. I don't think a sneaky attempt to get a bad answer through counts as a hidden gem, though. Colloquially, in English, a "gem" is a good thing to find, often by serendipity and unlooked for. That said, I totally concur with upvoting the late but good answer (the gem) while voting to delete the spam or nonsense answer (definitely not a gem!).